# CakePHP Merging date fields to the shortest

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach

I have 2 dates (create, update) that i want to merge in a new column, selecting the newest date... how can I do it?

Here is the array creation:

```
$this->Message= array(
                  'fields' => array('Message.id','Message.type','Message.createdate','Message.updatedate'),
                  'conditions' => $cond);
$messages = $this->Message->find('all', $conditionsMessage);
```

Now I need another field (lets call it `NewDate`) `Message.NewDate` that gets the newest date from `Message.createdate` and `Message.updatedate`, so i can call it after in a view using `$messages[NewDate]`

Help plz...

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

It's not hard to loop over the array with something like

```
foreach($messages as $k => $m){
    if(strtotime($m['Message']['updatedate']) > strtotime($m['Message']['createdate'])){
        $messages[$k]['Message']['NewDate'] = $m['Message']['updatedate'];
    }else{
        $messages[$k]['Message']['NewDate'] = $m['Message']['createdate'];
    }
}
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

I would think that your `Message.updatedate` would always be the newest date, so you could just select that. But assuming that's not the case for some reason, you can create a virtual field in your model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'NewDate' => "IF(Message.updatedate > Message.createdate, Message.updatedate, Message.createdate)"
);
```

This uses the MySQL `IF()` function. If you're not using MySQL you'd have to figure out how to do something similar with your database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if

Comment: Thx for the answer. Actually the updatedate is trully the newest date. But I can't use MySQL statments because of the rest of the code (I just simplified the above code to be easier to understand). I needed some array modification code, to create a new "column" with the calculated date... is there a way to use your MysQL code to an already created array?

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I just could put in the controller. I had to use it in the view!